# Connect face recognition model to database efficiently

Tags: python, face-recognition, yolo

I'm having a hard time connecting my facial recognition system (realtime) to the database.

I am using python language here. Try to imagine, when the system is doing REAL-TIME face detection and recognition, it will certainly form frame by frame during the process (looping logic), and I want if that face is recognized then the system will write 'known face' in the database. But this is the problem, because what if the upload to the database is done repeatedly because the same frame is continuously formed?

the question is, how do you make the system only upload 1 data to the database and if the other frames have the same image, the system doesn't need to upload data to the database?

Comment: You can probably create a cache of some kind to keep track of the latest seen time of the frame, and reject database update based on it.

Answer (score 0):

you dont show any code, but to do what you're asking you want to have a flag that detects when a face is found and sets the variable. Then clear the variable once the flag leaves the frame. to account for false positives you can wait 4-5 frames before clear the flags and see if the face is still in the frame (i.e someone turns their head and the tracking looses the face)